# createToken func is deprecated how to generate token from stripe in stripe 23.18.3?

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, stripe-payments

i want to use the create token function but its deprecated but in kotlin its still working how can i fetch the token from stripe?

import UIKit
import Foundation
import Stripe
import StripePaymentsUI

class StripeCardManager: NSObject, STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate {

```
static let shared = StripeCardManager()

private var successHandler: ((STPPaymentMethod) -> Void)?
private var failureHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)?

private override init() {
    super.init()
}

func presentAddCardViewController(from viewController: UIViewController, success: @escaping (STPPaymentMethod) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    self.successHandler = success
    self.failureHandler = failure

  
   
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared
         config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
         config.cardScanningEnabled = false

    let addCardViewController = STPAddCardViewController(configuration: .shared, theme: .defaultTheme)
        addCardViewController.delegate = self
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addCardViewController)
    viewController.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate

func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController) {
    addCardViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    failureHandler?(nil) // Invoke failure handler on cancellation
}

func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    // You can now dismiss the view controller
    addCardViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    successHandler?(paymentMethod) // Invoke success handler with token
    completion(nil)
}
```

}

```
func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    // You can now dismiss the view controller
    addCardViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    successHandler?(paymentMethod) // Invoke success handler with token
    completion(nil)
}
```

how can i use didCreatePaymentMethod in kotlin

im currently using didCreatePaymentMethod but i cant get the token from this i got stripe id which is no use for me which starts from pm i want which starts from tok

in ios i use paymentsheet so i dint have full account number also createToken function is deprecated.

Comment: `createToken()` was removed from stripe-android since [v16.0.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1600---2020-09-23). Creating token is a deprecated integration and it shouldn't be used. I'd recommend checking the latest guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet) to accept payment in Android. The latest version of stripe-android is only v20.35.1. I'm not too sure where you get v23.18.3 from.